# How do I filter tab-separated input by the count of fields with a given value?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, grep

My data(tab separated):

```
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
...
```

how can i grep the lines with exact, for example, 5 '1's,
ideal output:

```
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
```

Also, how can i grep lines with equal or more than (>=) 5 '1's,
ideal output:

```
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

i tried,

```
grep 1$'\t'1$'\t'1$'\t'1$'\t'1
```

however this will only output consecutive '1's, which is not all i want.

i wonder if there will be any simple method to achieve this, thank you!

Comment: Regular expressions are meant for matching patterns, not for counting.

Comment: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if(i==5{sum+=$i}}}if(sum==5)print $0}' file` would be untested, but close to a solution. Good luck.

Comment: ^^ `(i==5)` is wrong here. Plus one missing parenthesis, but I guess that one was typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[John Bollinger's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451124/45375) and [anishane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451090/45375) show that it *can* be done with `grep`, but, as has been noted, that is quite *cumbersome*, given that regular expression aren't designed for *counting*.

`awk`, by contrast, is built for *field-based* parsing and *counting* (often *combined* with regular expressions to identify field separators, or, as below, the fields themselves).

Assuming you have ***GNU* `awk`**, you can use the following:

Exactly 5 `1`s:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\<1\\>' 'NF==5' file
```

5 or more `1`s:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\<1\\>' 'NF>=5' file
```

- Special variable `FPAT` is a *GNU* `awk` extension that allows you to identify fields via a regex that describes the *fields themselves*, in contrast with the standard approach of using a regex to define the *separators* between fields (via special variable `FS` or option `-F`):

  - `'\\<1\\>'` identifies any "isolated" `1` (surrounded by non-word characters) as a field, based on word-boundary assertions `\<` and `\>`; the `\` must be doubled here so that the initial *string* parsing performed by `awk` doesn't "eat" single `\`s.
- Standard variable `NF` contains the *count* of input fields in the line at hand, which allows easy numerical comparison. If the conditional evaluates to true, the input line at hand is implicitly printed (in other words: `NF==5` is implicitly the same as `NF==5 { print }` and, more verbosely, `NF==5 { print $0 }`).

---

A **POSIX-compliant `awk` solution** is a little more complicated:

Exactly 5 `1`s:

```
awk '{ l=$0; gsub("[\t0]", "") }; length($0)==5 { print l }' file
```

5 or more `1`s:

```
awk '{ l=$0; gsub("[\t0]", "") }; length($0)>=5 { print l }' file
```

- `l=$0` saves the input line (`$0`) in its original form in variable `l`.
- `gsub("[\t0]", "")` replaces all `\t` and `0` chars. in the input line with the empty string, i.e., effectively removes them, and only leaves (directly concatenated) `1` instances (if any).
- `length($0)==5 { print l }` then prints the original input line (`l`) only if the resulting string of `1`s (i.e., the count of `1`s now stored in the *modified* input line (`$0`)) matches the specified count.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep`. But that would be an abuse of regex.

```
$ cat countme
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

$ grep -P '^[0\t]*(1[0\t]*){5}[0\t]*$' countme # Match exactly 5
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1

$ grep -P '^[0\t]*(1[0\t]*){5,}[0\t]*$' countme # Match >=5
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: should be countme?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to get lines with exactly five '1's:

```
grep '^[^1]*\(1[^1]*\)\{5,5\}[^1]*$'
```

You can simplify that to this for at least five '1's:

```
grep '\(1[^1]*\)\{5,\}'
```

The enumerated quantifier (`\{n,m\}`) enables you to conveniently specify a particular number or range of numbers of consecutive matches to a sub-pattern. To avoid matching lines with extra matches to such a pattern, however, you must also anchor it to the beginning and end of the line.

The other other trick is to make sure the gaps previous to the first `1`, between the `1`s, and after the last `1` are matched.  In your case, all of those gaps can be represented pretty simply as ranges of zero or more characters other than `1`: `[^1]*`.  Putting those pieces together gives you the above regular expressions.

Comment: "Exactly five" is just `\{5\}`, no need for `\{5,5\}`, is there?

Comment: @BenjaminW., both forms work.  I used `\{5,5\}` because it is more illustrative of enumerated quantifiers in general.  Indeed, I could have used just `\{5\}` in the second example, too, because that pattern is not anchored.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
sed -nE '/^([^1]*1[^1]*){5}$/p' your_file
```

for exactly 5 matches and

```
sed -nE '/^([^1]*1[^1]*){5,}$/p' your_file
```

for 5 or more matches.

---

**Note:** In GNU sed you may not see the `-E` option in the manpage, but it is supported. Using `-E` is for portability to, say, Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

with `perl`

```
$ perl -ane 'print if (grep {$_==1} @F) == 5' ip.txt 
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1

$ perl -ane 'print if (grep {$_==1} @F) >= 5' ip.txt 
1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

- `-a` to automatically split input line on whitespaces and save to `@F` array
- `grep {$_==1} @F` returns array with elements from `@F` array which are exactly equal to `1`
- `(grep {$_==1} @F) == 5` in scalar context, comparison will be done based on number of elements of array
- See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for details on `-ane` options